# dose response data analysis in R with drc

Tags: r

I m new in R,  I got data set with 3 variables (Herbicide doses, Weed-biotypes & Weed biomass(response)), I would like to analyse my data in dose-response logistic, non-linear model. Therefore I have activated "drc" packages with "MASS", but still the getting error message that- "could not find function "drm" or could not find function "multdrc" etc

anyone can help me please!!

```
>library(drc)

>IMGDM<-multdrc(mass~dose,id,fct=l3(),data=dataname)
>summary(IMGDM)
>anova(IMGDM)
>Model1<-drm(mass~dose,id, fct=l3(),data=datanmae)
>model2<-drc(mass~dose, id, data=dataname, fct=LL.4())
>modelFit(model2)
```

Comment: The package drc does have a function called `drm`, but does not appear to have a function called `drc` or `multidrc`. (There is a function called `multi2`).  Have you tried `help(package=drc)` ?

Comment: What version of `drc` are you using ? `multdrc` was available in an old version of `drc`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/drc/versions/1.5-5/topics/multdrc